# Error in deserializing body of request message for operation. C#

Tags: c#, web-services, soap

Im trying to consume a SoapWebService using c# but when i tried to consume the web service

```
Service.FindResRequest request = new Service.FindResRequest();
request.CodeService = "1010502";           
Service.FindResResponse response = portClient.FindService(Headers, request);
```

But it show up a error message:
**Error in deserializing body of request message for operation**

Inside of System.ServiceModel.CommunicationException > InnerException > [System.InvalidOperationException] "Error on XML document (1,1879)"

Inside of System.ServiceModel.CommunicationException > InnerException >  InnerException > [System.FormtException] {"The String" is not a valid Boolean"}

But if i change the property of the request it works, for example if i would like to make a request with the CodeStatus.

```
Service.FindResRequest request = new Service.FindResRequest();
request.CodeStatus = "1010502";           
Service.FindResResponse response = portClient.FindService(Headers, request);
```

Why it works with request.CodeStatus and it doesnt with reques.CodeService?

by the way, when i use SOAPUI and i make a request with CodeService, the response is successful.

Comment: I also use the Add Service Reference... option that Microsoft Visual C# 2010 has inside Project menu.

Comment: Can you show us the WSDL schema?